# How to fix jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologize if the question was answered. This is the code I refer to. But I have trouble using it. I'm still new to jQuery. Many thanks for the help

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 var aboutNav = $('.about-nav'),
  aboutNavTopPosition = aboutNav.offset().top,
  taglineOffesetTop = $('#intro-tagline').offset().top + $('#intro-tagline').height() + parseInt($('#intro-tagline').css('paddingTop').replace('px', '')),
  contentSections = $('.section');
 
 $(window).on('scroll', function(){
  //on desktop - assign a position fixed to logo and action button and move them outside the viewport
  ( $(window).scrollTop() > taglineOffesetTop ) ? $('#logo, .btn').addClass('is-hidden') : $('#logo, .btn').removeClass('is-hidden');
  
  //on desktop - fix about navigation on scrolling
  if($(window).scrollTop() > aboutNavTopPosition ) {
   //fix about navigation
   aboutNav.addClass('is-fixed');
   //push the .main-content giving it a top-margin
   $('.main-content').addClass('has-top-margin'); 
   //on Firefox CSS transition/animation fails when parent element changes position attribute
   //so we to change about navigation childrens attributes after having changed its position value
   setTimeout(function() {
             aboutNav.addClass('animate-children');
             $('#logo').addClass('slide-in');
    $('.btn').addClass('slide-in');
         }, 50);
  } else {
   aboutNav.removeClass('is-fixed');
   $('.main-content').removeClass('has-top-margin');
   setTimeout(function() {
             aboutNav.removeClass('animate-children');
             $('#logo').removeClass('slide-in');
    $('.btn').removeClass('slide-in');
         }, 50);
  }

  //on desktop - update the active link in the about fixed navigation
  updateaboutNavigation();
 });
 //smooth scrolling when clicking on the about navigation items
 aboutNav.find('ul a').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var target= $(this.hash);
        $('body,html').animate({
         'scrollTop': target.offset().top - aboutNav.height() + 1
         }, 400
        ); 
        //on mobile - close about navigation
        $('.about-nav-trigger').removeClass('menu-is-open');
        aboutNav.find('ul').removeClass('is-visible');
    });
});
```

My problem is that the code for the sticky side menu on the bottom doesn't work because the second line of code

```js
aboutNavTopPosition = aboutNav.offset().top,
```

I have replaced it. but still unsuccessful.

Comment: You probably aren't including a reference to jQuery. Do you have your HTML code?

Comment: can you write your html code also

Comment: Exactly it fails in HTML. thank you very much